# Select items from two custom lists based on multiple join criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have to custom data lists:

```
    public class DatType1
{

    public string yr;
    public string qr;
    public string mt;
    public string cw;
    public string tar;
    public string rg;
    public string mac;
    public string fuel;
    public double fp;
    public double fi;
    public double fd;

}
```

and

```
public class DatType2
{

    public string yr;
    public string qr;
    public string mt;
    public string cw;
    public string tar;
    public string RG;
    public double pp;
    public double pi;
    public double fp;
    public double fi;
    public double fd;


}
```

As you can see there is a lot of overlap between the two. I would like to add the values for DatType1.fp, DatType1.fi, DatType1.fd to DateType2 but I need to put them in the right place, the right place means where a bunch of the items are equal.

I have looked a lot on the site here but couldnt figure it out. I have tried sth like this:

```
from a in TableA
from b in TableB
where a.yr==b.yr & a.qr==b.qr & a.RG == b.RG & a.tar ==b.tar
select( r=> new DatType2{....}
```

and then in the brackets repeat everything from DateType2 that I want to keep and add DatType1.fp, DatType1.fi, DatType1.fd.

If I did this with brute force I would do a double for loop and go through each line of DatType1 and see where I match a row in DatType2 and then add DatType1.fp, DatType1.fi, DatType1.fd - But this would be very slow

This however didnt work and is far from elegant! ...:) 
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, you are using `&`, a bitwise comparison operator. I think you should use `&&` instead.

Comment: You should really use more meaningful variable names, rather than abbreviating everything to such an extent.  It will make your code *much* easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a base class, with all the common data:

```
public class BaseClass    
{
    public string yr;
    public string qr;
    public string mt;
    public string cw;
    public string tar;
    public string rg;
    public double fp;
    public double fi;
    public double fd;

    public void SetAllValues(BaseClass Other)
    {
        this.yr = Other.yr;
        this.qr = Other.qr;
        //til the end.
        this.fd = Other.fd;
    }

    //with this you check the equal stuff...
    public bool HasSameSignature(BaseClass Other)
    { 
        if (this.yr != Other.yr) return false;
        if (this.qr != Other.qr) return false;  
        //all other comparisons needed
        return true;
    }

    //with this you set the desired ones:
    public void SetDesired(BaseClass Other)
    {
        this.fp = Other.fp;
        this.fi = Other.fi;
        //all other settings needed
    }
}
```

And the others would inherit this base:

```
public class DatType1 : BaseClass
{
    public string mac;
    public string fuel;
}


public class DatType2 : BaseClass
{
    public double pp;
    public double pi;
}
```

Now you can use the `a.HasSameSignature(b)` instead of `a.yr==b.yr & a.qr==b.qr & a.RG == b.RG & a.tar ==b.tar`.
And Set the values (or create a copy method, as you wish)....

Comment: thanks Daniel. the problem is there is a lot of computing going on beforehand that I cannot really change. So i have two lists with these two datatypes and I need to combine them somehow. I dont really see how I would do that with your proposal!? But obviously that might be me not getting it...

Comment: What I dont get is where do you loop?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend overloading the equality comparison of the two objects to make the `DatType1:IEquatable<DatType2>` and/or `DatType2:IEquatable<DatType1>`. That would allow you to use `dat1.Equals(dat2)` or `dat2.Equals(dat1)`.

Alternatively, you can implement a comparison delegate and pass that in as `dat1.Equals(dat2,comparer)` or `comparer.Compare(dat1,dat2)`. The later is probably ideal if you don't have control over the `DatType1` or `DatType2` types.